# MFC: How do you get the + indicator to show when using the CImageList/CListCtrl/CTreeCtrl method for drag and drop operations?

Tags: mfc, drag-and-drop

I'm using the MS technique shown in `Q148738` for starting a drag operation going from a listview to a treeview.  The drag starts via `LVN_BEGINDRAG`, having the `CListCtrl::CreateDragImage` create the drag image, `BeginDrag()`, `DragEnter()`.  Then using `OnMouseMove` to move the image, etc..  See [`Q148738`](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/148/Q148738/) for details.  One thing I don't see is how to create the + sign to indicate a copy operation instead of move for the drag operation as the `Ctrl` key is pressed or released.  Is that built in to MFC controls using this technique or would I need to somehow create my own overlay?  If I have to do it myself, what is the correct way to implement it?

TIA!!

Comment: Please provide the link for Q148738.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120712062812if_/http://download.microsoft.com/download/vc60pro/demo4/1/win98/en-us/mfcdrag.exe